# Detect windows 2008 server and windows 2003 server in C#

Tags: c#, operating-system

Can someone help me modify this code to support Windows 2003 and Windows 2008 server?
Thanks

```
 public static string getOSLegacy()
       {
           //Get Operating system information.
           OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
           //Get version information about the os.
           Version vs = os.Version;

           //Variable to hold our return value
           string operatingSystem = "";

           if (os.Platform == PlatformID.Win32Windows)
           {
               //This is a pre-NT version of Windows
               switch (vs.Minor)
               {
                   case 0:
                       operatingSystem = "95";
                       break;
                   case 10:
                       if (vs.Revision.ToString() == "2222A")
                           operatingSystem = "98SE";
                       else
                           operatingSystem = "98";
                       break;
                   case 90:
                       operatingSystem = "Me";
                       break;
                   default:
                       break;
               }
           }
           else if (os.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
           {
               switch (vs.Major)
               {
                   case 3:
                       operatingSystem = "NT 3.51";
                       break;
                   case 4:
                       operatingSystem = "NT 4.0";
                       break;
                   case 5:
                       if (vs.Minor == 0)
                       {
                           operatingSystem = "2000";
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           operatingSystem = "XP";
                       }
                       break;
                   case 6:
                       if (vs.Minor == 0)
                       {
                           operatingSystem = "Vista";
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           operatingSystem = "7";
                       }
                       break;
                   default:
                       break;
               }
           }

           return operatingSystem;
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>2003 is 5.2. 2008 is 6.1.</s>

<s>This post contains the missing pieces: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/5956c04f-072a-406c-ae6a-cc8b3a207936</s>

**Edit:** This answer is incomplete as noted by the comments. [Slavik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5997059) and the linked article are a much better approach IMHO. In particular, the wProductType byte (that is not present in the .NET API) contains key information.

Comment: This answer is rubbish since both Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 has same version (6.1)  and Win XP 64 bit has same version as Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Agree. This answer features false information (and the linked code too): it states that Win7 is 6.2, but 6.2 is Win8

Answer (score 2):

On Server 2003, Version returns 5.2.3790.131072.
On Server 2008, Version returns 6.0.6002.131072.

(On Windows 7 it's 6.1.7600.0).

Also, you can get the full OS name from the registry at:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion, key ProductName.

Comment: My 2008 returns 6.0 but I'm not running R2. It's possible that R2 is 6.1.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2008 R2 is different from not R2.
See details here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/OSVersionInfo.aspx

My code to detect R2:

```
    public static bool Win7;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetVersionEx(ref OSVERSIONINFOEX osVersionInfo);

    #region OSVERSIONINFOEX
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct OSVERSIONINFOEX
    {
        public int dwOSVersionInfoSize;
        public int dwMajorVersion;
        public int dwMinorVersion;
        public int dwBuildNumber;
        public int dwPlatformId;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
        public string szCSDVersion;
        public short wServicePackMajor;
        public short wServicePackMinor;
        public short wSuiteMask;
        public byte wProductType;
        public byte wReserved;
    }
    #endregion OSVERSIONINFOEX

    static MyMethod () {

        Version ver = System.Environment.OSVersion.Version;
        OperatingSystem osVersion = Environment.OSVersion;
        OSVERSIONINFOEX osVersionInfo = new OSVERSIONINFOEX();
        osVersionInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));

        GetVersionEx(ref osVersionInfo);
        byte productType = osVersionInfo.wProductType;

        if (ver.Major==6 & ver.Minor==1 & productType==1) {
            Win7=true;
            }
        else {
            Win7=false;
            }

        if (ver.Major==6 & ver.Minor==1 & productType==3)
            Report.Info ("OS is Windows Server 2008 R2");
        else //here standart methods can be used...
            Report.Info ("ver.Major: "+ver.Major.ToString()+"\r\nver.Minor: "+ver.Minor.ToString()+"\r\nproductType: "+productType.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Win32 you use the wProductType of the OSVERSIONINFOEX to determine this. It seems strange that this information doesn't seem to be available thru .NET. Perhaps it is somewhere that I haven't found. At any rate I would be nervous about relying on version #'s to distinguish server vs. non-server operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I needed my application to capture computer info for possible bug-reports and statistics.

**I did not find the solutions where an *application manifest* had to be added satisfactory.** Most of the suggestions I found while googling this suggested just that, unfortunately.

Thing is, when using a manifest, each OS version has to be added manually to it in order for that particular OS version to be able to report itself at runtime.

In other words, this becomes a race condition: A user of my app may very well be using a version of my app that *pre-dates* the OS in use. I would have to upgrade the app **immediately** when a new OS version was launched by Microsoft. I would also have to force the users to upgrade the app at the same time as they updated the OS.

In other words, **not very feasible.**

After browsing through the options I found some references (surprisingly few compared to the app manifest) that instead suggested using registry lookups.

Check out this chart from MS in regards to mapping to OS releases: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832.aspx

My (chopped down) `ComputerInfo` class with only `WinMajorVersion`, `WinMinorVersion` and `IsServer` properties looks like this:

using Microsoft.Win32;

```
namespace Inspection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Static class that adds convenient methods for getting information on the running computers basic hardware and os setup.
    /// </summary>
    public static class ComputerInfo
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns the Windows major version number for this computer.
        /// </summary>
        public static uint WinMajorVersion
        {
            get
            {
                dynamic major;
                // The 'CurrentMajorVersionNumber' string value in the CurrentVersion key is new for Windows 10, 
                // and will most likely (hopefully) be there for some time before MS decides to change this - again...
                if (TryGeRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentMajorVersionNumber", out major))
                {
                    return (uint) major;
                }

                // When the 'CurrentMajorVersionNumber' value is not present we fallback to reading the previous key used for this: 'CurrentVersion'
                dynamic version;
                if (!TryGeRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentVersion", out version))
                    return 0;

                var versionParts = ((string) version).Split('.');
                if (versionParts.Length != 2) return 0;
                uint majorAsUInt;
                return uint.TryParse(versionParts[0], out majorAsUInt) ? majorAsUInt : 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns the Windows minor version number for this computer.
        /// </summary>
        public static uint WinMinorVersion
        {
            get
            {
                dynamic minor;
                // The 'CurrentMinorVersionNumber' string value in the CurrentVersion key is new for Windows 10, 
                // and will most likely (hopefully) be there for some time before MS decides to change this - again...
                if (TryGeRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentMinorVersionNumber",
                    out minor))
                {
                    return (uint) minor;
                }

                // When the 'CurrentMinorVersionNumber' value is not present we fallback to reading the previous key used for this: 'CurrentVersion'
                dynamic version;
                if (!TryGeRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentVersion", out version))
                    return 0;

                var versionParts = ((string) version).Split('.');
                if (versionParts.Length != 2) return 0;
                uint minorAsUInt;
                return uint.TryParse(versionParts[1], out minorAsUInt) ? minorAsUInt : 0;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns whether or not the current computer is a server or not.
        /// </summary>
        public static uint IsServer
        {
            get
            {
                dynamic installationType;
                if (TryGeRegistryKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "InstallationType",
                    out installationType))
                {
                    return (uint) (installationType.Equals("Client") ? 0 : 1);
                }

                return 0;
            }
        }

        private static bool TryGeRegistryKey(string path, string key, out dynamic value)
        {
            value = null;
            try
            {
                var rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path);
                if (rk == null) return false;
                value = rk.GetValue(key);
                return value != null;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The race condition you describe is exactly why the new behaviour was implemented. Unless you're designing a system information tool, the OS version is information you don't need to know.

Comment: @EKW, In my scenario I needed the 'system information' aspect to report on user's version for license reporting, statistics and support. I would agree though that the information provided probably should not be (ab)used to control logic in the code in regards to which features to use or not.